# Validate existing records with overlap item ranges taking nil as infinite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, activemodel

I'm here because I've been looking around for some queries that could help to find existing records with overlapping item ranges but I couldn't find anything. Let's say I have a model named `Cart`.  A Cart has the following attributes: `item_min` and `item_max` where `item_max` is nullable and will be taken as infinite when nil.  In my model, I want to add a validation so no records with overlapping item ranges could be saved.

I have created a query but it's not working for all my test cases:

```
saved cart: item_min: 2, item_max: nil
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 1` VALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 2` VALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 6` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 4, item_max: 7` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_cart: 4, item_max: nil` INVALID
```

```
saved cart: `item_min: 2, item_max: 7`
try to save `cart: item_min: 1, item_max: 1` VALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 8, item_max: 10` VALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 8, item_max: nil` VALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 2` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 8` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: 5` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 5, item_max: 10` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 3, item_max: 5` INVALID
try to save cart: `item_min: 1, item_max: nil` INVALID
```

I created the following query:

```
  def validate_item_count_range
    if item_count_max.nil?
      overlap_carts = Cart.where(item_count_max: nil)
    else
      overlap_carts = Cart.where(
        "item_count_min >= ? AND item_count_max <= ?", item_count_min, item_count_max,
      ).or(
        Cart.where(
          "item_count_min <= ? AND item_count_max IS NULL", item_count_min,
        ),
      )
    end

    errors.add(:item_count_min, "overlaps with existing carts") if overlap_carts.present?
  end
```

However, this validation is not working for all my test cases. Could you please help me to improve my query so mi test cases could pass?

BTW, I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Range#overlaps?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Range.html#method-i-overlaps-3F), [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) and [`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-any-3F)

Without special SQL query

```
if Cart.pluck(:item_min, :item_max).any? { |min, max| (min..max).overlaps?(item_min..item_max) }
  errors.add(:base, :overlaps_with_existing_carts)
end
```

An endless range has a definite begin value, but a `nil` end value. You can omit this `nil`

```
(8..nil) == (8..)
# => true
```

Such a range includes all values from the begin value

```
(8..nil).overlaps?(4..6)
# => false

(8..nil).overlaps?(4..9)
# => true
```

And of course this method works with usual ranges

```
(4..6).overlaps?(6..8)
# => true

(4..6).overlaps?(1..3)
# => false
```

As Jad wrote in comment, the performance of such validation with arrays will be low if there are million records. The idea for SQL query using [built-in ranges in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

```
if Cart.exists?(["numrange(item_count_min, item_count_max, '[]') && numrange(?, ?, '[]')", item_count_min, item_count_max])
  errors.add(:base, :overlaps_with_existing_carts)
end
```

RDBMS will optimize such query. It will be much more effective than operate with giant array

`[]` in this query means inclusive lower and upper bounds (by default upper bound is exclusive)

Using `NULL` means that the range is unbounded

`&&` operator checks overlaps

```sql
SELECT numrange(10, NULL, '[]') && numrange(20, 40, '[]');
-- ?column? 
-- ----------
--  t

SELECT numrange(10, 20, '[]') && numrange(20, 40, '[]');
-- ?column? 
-- ----------
--  t
```

Comment: depending on the number of `Cart`s you're playing with you might want to filter them (before `pluck`), something like "where item_min <= new_item_max or item_max >= new_item_min" but the above code should be good until you have 1000 carts or so :)